# “Your carrier may charge for sms messages used to activate iCloud” message keeps popping up

Tags: iphone, icloud, sms

After trying solutions I have found with people that had the same problem, I still am getting this message popping up. It usually happens when the reception is weak in some locations and it goes from 1 bar to 0 bars. The message pops up again as soon as I acknowledge it, rendering my phone unusable because I can’t do anything except continuing to press the Ok button just for it to pop up again half a second later. I can’t turn it to Airplane Mode because it pops up too quickly and I can’t do anything else on the phone until I press the Ok or Cancel button.

What I’ve tried so far is turning off FaceTime, turning off every option for messages, and I’ve turned off every option I could find in iCloud.

I have the iPhone 11. Updated to 15.6.1

Am I missing anything? What else can I do?  I wish it would remember what I choose and maybe remind me in a month or a week. It seems it tries to remind me every time my signal goes from no signal to some signal (this happens a lot when inside buildings with poor reception). I just want to take pictures but I can’t because my phone is unusable when this happens. So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I did approach an authorized iPhone dealer/repair centre. Since I was using the latest iPhone 14, I had been given the option to swap to a new phone. Unfortunately, the issue was unable to be solved. I changed to a new sim card with a totally different service provider. Then the message stops popping up. It was a relief.

Comment: So, it was a carrier issue?  Did you try contacting the carrier for assistance?